# Upload an Image (with description) to Tumblr

Tags: php, post, tumblr, image

so I want to have a .php script that uploads an image every 3 hours to my Tumblr (via a cronjob). I used to have a working script, however since Tumblr no longer supports their v1 API I am lost. I have found no good guides on Google (http://vigrond.com/blog/2012/02/04/oauth-extension-php-and-the-tumblr-api/ doesn't do it for me since I can't install the OAuth extension) and the official Tumblr Documentation doesn't even exist.

I would be very glad if you can help me out and point me to a solution :)

I've found this would be a good start: https://gist.github.com/1649885 but I cannot seem to get the access_token / access_secret.

Comment: use tumblr's queue post option?

Comment: @popnoodles with PHP? ...

Comment: not without using cURL but if that works you could post normally every 3 hours anyway. Have you tried using cURL?

Comment: "official tumblr documentation" [exists here.](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)  See first: section "Authentication" re: access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a simple script that posts a random image, taken from a random category, each category has its own tags and captions file, so for every image posted, you can have several captions.

the script is using the tumblr api v2.

[matteobononi.it tumblr random image post script](http://www.matteobononi.it/tumblr_random_image_post.php)